# List of Windows Native Functions for XP, VISTA and Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi

On the MSDN is there some sort of reference which details every native function inside the Windows API for different versions say from Windows XP upwards?

I have been googling and looking round the MSDN but I must not be looking for the correct thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: Every API doc page tells you which versions of windows it supports. Is that not what you're after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are pages that will tell you what is new. As Microsoft maintains almost 100% backward compatibility with older versions, the only difference is additions.

E.g. [new in Windows 7 and 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee461765(VS.85).aspx)